# User is tracking tag badge for non-existing tag with emoji

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tag-badges, badge-progress

[This user on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks?tab=topactivity) is tracking their next tag badge, for a tag that does not exist. It's the dragon emoji:

[image]

They're doing it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks?tab=topactivity) too. I doubt the tag ever existed; given the user's history it's more likely they've hijacked the call to the server when selecting which tag badge to track.

Comment: [Asked and answered on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382516) (though apparently it was fixed?)

Comment: It's a [dragon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqCTY.png)

Comment: Ah, I've missed that one.

Comment: Thats kinda clever :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As answered in the [MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382516), at the time they began tracking that nonexistent badge, the system allowed anyone to track any tag badge, regardless of whether the tag existed or not.

Today, the system prevents people from trying to set a nonexistent tag as their target badge, but those who previously set a nonexistent tag as their target back when it was allowed can still continue to keep it there.

**Update:** It appears that the team has reset the indicator for those who were previously tracking nonexistent badges back when this was allowed.