# It's possible to track your progress for a badge you can't earn (anymore)

Tags: bug, profile-page, badge-progress

It's possible to hijack the "Select your next badge" call and choose a badge which you've already earned, or one which doesn't even display (e.g. [Marshal if you're a ♦ moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146173/295232)).

Steps to reproduce:

- Visit your [profile page](/users/current)
- Open the browser console
- Find your [`fkey`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74154/295232) (it's in one of the `<script>` elements)
- Insert the `fkey` and the badge name into the following jQuery snippet, and execute it in the console:

  ```
  $.post("/users/activity/next-badge-popup/save",
         "fkey=[YOUR FKEY HERE]&badgeDatabaseName=[BADGE NAME]&isTagBadge=false")
  ```
- [Profit!](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/7297/glorfindel)

Note that the badge does need to exist on the site; e.g. you can't use this to track the Informed badge on a child meta.

I'd expect some server side check on this as well, though it's obviously not as open to abuse as [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331305/295232).

Comment: And now you fool exactly 1 person...